# Can't load resources in a gradle project

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline

I am using gradle 4.10.2 & IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2
Note that this is a jenkins shared library project, hence, deviates from the [standard gradle project structure](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html).
[image]

The project shown in the image is an existing Gradle project. I am simply trying to load a properties file viz. mailTemplate.properties in a Groovy class EmailTemplate but the problem is that irrespective of where I keep it(like shown in the image), it's not loaded. I created a separate test gradle project and placed it in the default (src/main/resources) dir. and it works like a breeze.
I tried creating 'resources' at two places but in vain.

The build.gradle is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ivy {
            url "$repositoryURL/$resolveRepository"
        }
        maven {
            url "$repositoryURL/$resolveRepository"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "tools.gradle.plugin:ReleasePlugin:1.10.0"
        classpath "tools.gradle.plugin:qualityreport:v1.14.4"
    }
}

group 'tools'

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'tools.gradle.plugin.releaseplugin'
apply plugin: 'tools.gradle.plugin.qualityreport'

sourceSets {
    main {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
    test {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['test/groovy']
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    addAll(buildscript.repositories)
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15'
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:2.4.9'
    compile 'com.cloudbees:groovy-cps:1.1'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'
    testCompile 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.6.4'
    testCompile ('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4') {
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy'
    }
    testCompile gradleTestKit()
    testCompile group: 'com.lesfurets', name: 'jenkins-pipeline-unit', version: '1.1'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.23.4'
    testCompile group: 'tools.gradle.plugin', name: 'jenkins-shared-stages', version: 'v2.48.0'

    // jenkins dependencies
    testCompile 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins:script-security:1.34@jar'
}

task copySharedLibs(type: Copy, group: "PipelineTest") {
    from '.'
    into 'build/libs/jenkins-shared-pipelines@master'
    include 'src/**'
    include 'vars/**'
}

test.dependsOn(copySharedLibs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Gradle `groovy plugin` expects resources to be at `src/main/resources` by default. In case the resources are located some other folder then it should be configured in the `sourceSets`. You can try the below assuming your resource file are also withing your `src` folder.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['src']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
    test {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['test/groovy']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['test/groovy']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Complementing this answer, Gradle assumes the [Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Comment: Do you mean resources {
            srcDirs = ['resources']
        }

Comment: It depends on the structure of your application. As the image you posted it should be
    resources {
        srcDirs = ['src']
    }

Comment: @KaliyugAntagonist 
Yes it is but [Gradle follows that as well](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_project_layout) (when using the `java` plugin), at least in the `src/main/java` & `src/test/java` & `/resources`. However my comment was wrong because I don't think they use it for all the components of that layout (`/filters` etc) and I presented it as a fact which is not! It seems to be the rationale behind it though.